# Editor Template does not work with DisplayFormat

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to create an Editor Template for a DateTime field and it does not seem to respect my DisplayFormat attribute.

My model:

```
public class Project
{
    [Display(Name="Project Name")]
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Start Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

My Editor Template in folder /Views/Projects/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model, new { @class="datepicker" })
```

Here is the View that ties everything together:

```
@model Project

<fieldset>
    <legend>Project</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProjectName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

When I have it this way then I am seeing the time portion of the date. When I remove the editor template then it works fine and only shows the date portion. Why does it seem to ignore DisplayFormat when I have an Editor Template?

Comment: Duplicate of this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697872/why-is-displayformat-dataformatstring-not-working/21135140?noredirect=1#comment33310399_21135140

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's first look at what happens when you don't use a template. I have added the generic type to make it even more explicit what the difference is.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor<Product>(product => product.StartDate)
```

Now let's look at your template editor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor<DateTime?>(dateTime => dateTime)
```

Notice the difference? In the latter case you are simply dealing with a DateTime instance, which means that you are losing the metadata defined by the model's property.

By using a template you are the one responsible for handling the metadata, which should be provided to your template in `ViewData.ModelMetadata.*`. For example in your case you will need to format the date yourself using `ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString`

Comment: So what is the solution? How do I format the date myself using ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString? Example please.

Comment: `Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class="datepicker" })` - `""` means current model.

Answer (score 4):

The DisplayFormat will be applied if you change your editor template to:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

To make your date property HTML5 compliant, add the DataType.Date attribute to your model property:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name="Start Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

And add an editor template for date at /Views/Projects/EditorTemplates/Date.cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "datePicker", type = "date" })
```

Answer (score 0):

change to `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @class="datepicker" })`

Comment: Care to send me your solution?

Comment: https://github.com/hazzik/beerconf-website/blob/master/src/Web/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml but i'm not using DataAnnotations for generating model metadata, but it should be exactly the same. Note, that `settings.ToHtmlAttributes()` just a glue for generating additional html attributes, as `new { @class="datepicker" }` in your sample