# Why is DisplayFormat DataFormatString not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a property in my view model as follows:

```
[Editable(false)]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime MovementDate { get; set; }
```

Yet the markup

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MovementDate)
</td>
```

renders the date value as `2013/05/15 12:00:00 AM`.

What am I doing wrong? My model:

```
public class WithDateModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
    public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }
    public WithDateModel()
    {
        TheDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@model ParkPay.WebTests.Models.WithDateModel
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TheDate)
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

What gets rendered:

```
2013/05/25 02:23:37 AM
```

Comment: Do you only want to display the date? The `DateTime` structure is an expression of a date and time.

Comment: @MattSull87 I am well aware that the DateTime structure includes times. That is exactly why I am trying to use teh `DataFormatString` property to exclude the time from the formatted date.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? Answer of any assistance?

Comment: It wasn't working for me, because i didn't use `@Html.DisplayFor()`. I commented this here in case other people will do the same mistake.

Comment: Use [DataType(DataType.Date] to only return the DATE part of DATETIME.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why are you using `ApplyFormatInEditMode` if you have set `[Editable(false)]`? All `ApplyFormatInEditMode` does is format the date if you have it in a text box or something for editing, which you probably won't because of the aforementioned.

I was able to get the date to display correctly using the following:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
public DateTime Date 
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
    set
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

and in the view (with resulting output):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)        // 2013/05/23
<br />
@Model.Date                          // 23/05/2013 09:57:56
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Date)    // 2013/05/23
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is much easier to have a superfluous `ApplyFormatInEditMode ` on each `DisplayFormat` attribute than to have to add or remove it if I add or remove the `[Editable(false)]` attribute.

Answer (score 49):

If you can't get it working on the model, you could try it on the view.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValidFrom, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {maxlength = 10})
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Also, as a side-note, DisplayFormat is ignored in "TextBoxFor".

Comment: DisplayFormat is ignored in "TextBoxFor" - Gotta love microsoft's consistency here :(

Comment: @AdamTolley agree, completely anti-intuitive

Comment: Wouldn't this essentially be considered 'hard-coding it' though? I'm using `EditorFor()` and it's not working either; and I'd REALLY rather not have to 'hard-code' it.

Comment: Apparently, the attribute works well for `@Html.EditorFor` and not the other helpers. You can use the EditorFor helper and you can always add your custom class using `@Html.EditorFor(x=> x.MyProperty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "MyCssClass" } })`

Answer (score 6):

**Since You want to exclude the time to get Only Date**:
At Model:-

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}"]
   public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }
```

At Views:-

```
    @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.TheDate)
    @Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(model => model.TheDate)
```

The tutorial of the following link may help you.It works for me.

http://ilyasmamunbd.blogspot.com/2014/02/jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar.html

Comment: Setting `ApplyFormatInEditMode` did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case a teammate had defined a global display template (aka `~\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`) that I didn't realize took precedence over my `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]` on my model property.

The solution was to move my format string to new shared template, so the attribute changes to:

```
// see ~\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\DateMyFormat.cshtml for formatting
[UIHint("DateMyFormat")]
public DateTime MovementDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to annotate the type as Date

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

Comment: This annotation creates an HTML5 date input rather than a textbox, which may or may not be the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

In the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Athlete.Models
{
    public class Foo
    {

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime SignDate
        {
           get;
           set;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the view:

```
<td style="text-align:left;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SignDate)</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a datepicker which was showing the date in the wrong order. Fixed it by using the HTML 5 value field. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

```
<input asp-for="From" type="text" class="pickadate picker__input" value="@Model?.From.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")">
```

Answer (score 0):

Very old post I know, but this was the top result when I was searching for my problem. The solution for me was making the property nullable with the '?' operator.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the price per gallon at fillup")]
public decimal? GasPricePerGallon { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -3):

You need the var name in the Display Name:

[Display(Name = "**MovementDate**")] 

public DateTime **MovementDate** { get; set; }

```
[Editable(false)]
[Display(Name = "MovementDate")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime MovementDate { get; set; }
```