# What is the proper data annotation to format my decimal property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, poco

I have a POCO with a decimal property called SizeUS.  I would like to use data annotations to format the display of the decimal in a view.  My SizeUS property is only displaying 2 decimal places in my view and I want it to display 4 decimal places.  What is the proper data annotation to accomplish this ?

```
[DisplayFormat( ? )]
public decimal SizeUS {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:#.####}")]
```

See [Custom Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for formats and [`DisplayFormatAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for examples

Comment: If you want the 4 decimals to display in edit mode also, use `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` in the above `DisplyaFormat` declaration.

Comment: What's the `{0:` bit mean/do?

Comment: @MattBaker it's a format item. `0` being the first item. See the documentation for [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting).

Comment: Remember that DisplayFormat is ignored in "TextBoxFor", check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21135140/1216184) to format through TextBoxFor passing the template as argument