# DataAnnotations: DisplayFormat not being honored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have tried both this:

```
[Display(Name = "Contract Value")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0.##}")]
public decimal ContractValue { get; set; }
```

And this:

```
[Display(Name = "Contract Value")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0.##}")]
public decimal ContractValue { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => contractInfoModel.ContractValue)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => contractInfoModel.ContractValue, new { maxlength = "100" })
```

If  I do this, it works.  But I don't want to do this:

```
<input type="text" name="@Html.NameFor(x=>contractInfoModel.ContractValue)" id="@Html.IdFor(x=>contractInfoModel.ContractValue)" value="@Model.ContractInfoM.ContractValue.ToString("0.##")" class="numeric" maxlength="10" />
```

The Display Name works great.  But it still shows 4 decimal places.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing the hashmarks with zeros. I'm not sure if it works, but give it a try.

Comment: Nope!  Worth a shot, but no

Comment: Then try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848969/what-is-the-proper-data-annotation-to-format-my-decimal-property

Comment: yeah I saw that already.  This also does not work: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:#.####}")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

By design, the DisplayFormat is not honored in a TextBoxFor.  So instead of this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => contractInfoModel.ContractValue, new { maxlength = "10" })
```

I did this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => contractInfoModel.ContractValue, new { maxlength = "10" })
```

And it works great.

Comment: If you want to use `TextBoxFor()` its `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => contractInfoModel.ContractValue, "{0.##}", new { maxlength = "10" })`