# MVC DateFormat short

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: dd-mm-yyyy}")]
public DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
```

This is in my `Data Model` and it's giving is `01/01/2015`

But I need in this format `January/01/2015` result.

I have tried using the `ToShortDateString()`. But I am having

> error Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

As much as possible. I want it to be in the models instead of using the View. But if it can't be help.

What ever works is fine.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16697872/993547

Comment: `DataFormatString = "{0: MMMM/dd/yy}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this;

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: MMMM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
```

Reference: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you are, however, stuck to a single dateformat, you can also "hack" your View without touching the model.

Something like this;

```
<div>
  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
     <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateProcessed)</dt>
     <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateProcessed)</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Becomes;

```
<div>
  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
     <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateProcessed)</dt>
     <dd>
         @{string formattedDate = Model.DateProcessed.ToString("MMMM/dd/yyyy");}
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => formattedDate)
     </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Which will show the date in the correct format.

Comment: Wow, you updated your answer. I was waiting for the 10 mins so I can accept the answer. So I shut my eyes, then walla.  Woke up 15 hours after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: MMMM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
```

And if you don't use date format in your model class then try below on :

**First Set your date property as below**

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateProcessed { get; set; }
```

then your in your **View** like this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateProcessed,"{0: MMMM/dd/yyyy}", placeholder = "MMMM/dd/yyyy" })
```