# Not able to set the date format to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: model-view-controller

I am doing all what is said on the net to set the date date format but without success.

In my model:

```
//[DataType(DataType.DateTime)] I TRIED WITH AND WITHOUT THIS LINE
        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

And in my view, simply

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}",new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line" })
```

I Try to enter May 14th 2016 this way: 14/05/2016 and it doesnt work. To get my "may 14th" I still need to enter 05/14/2016. Can anyone explain me why so it is?
Thank you

Comment: Just saw it.. thanks but it does not solved the prob

Comment: Try `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`

Comment: See my code, I try with and without

Comment: `DataType.Date` not `DataType.DateTime` and `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]`

Comment: Sorry, just saw "Date" instead of "Datetime". I ve tryed but it doesnt work. And ApplyFormatInEditMode = true neither

Comment: If I copy the generated html, and remove "data-val-date=..."  my format dd/mm/yyyy aplies! But then If the user enter anything, the errror is not catch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is DisplayFormat DataFormatString not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697872/why-is-displayformat-dataformatstring-not-working)