# How can capture Month/Year in an Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to capture `DateTime` with the following format `MM/yyyy`. My view-model looks like this

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? TargetMonth { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have razor's editor-template called `Date.cshtml` with the following code

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

When I select/type value like this `07/2018` I get the following error during the client-side validation

> The field Target Month must be a date.

How can I correctly capture the month using the `MM/yyyy` format?

Comment: Make it a dropdown for month (1 to 12) and make the year a numeric field. I think that is a better UI design. You can restrict min and max for the year too. If you want a single input, use a masked input box and make the property string. Or make the property string and apply regex to it for validation.

Answer (score 2):

I've replicated your issue on a sample project. The problem is that the DisplayFormat attribute is ignored in TextBox helpers ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21135140/1469976)).

I would recommend going for an existing datepicker library, there are plenty of good solutions to choose from. I've found a [JS Fiddle using Bootstrap Datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/k5zookLt/20/) that addresses your Month picker requirement.

Html:

`<input type="text" class="monthPicker" placeholder="CheckIn" >`

JS:

```
$('.monthPicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    format: 'mm/yyyy'
})
```

You can change your editor template to use this datepicker.

Comment: The issue is not how to display a picker.  The issue on how to bind the value correctly to the view model. I am already using a bootstrap-picker but that just to provide an easy way for the user to select a date.

Comment: The issue is that client side validation is not working. I pointed out that this is due to the DisplayFormat being ignored and offered an alternative for client side validation.

Comment: Maybe I should also point that the DataType.Date client validation is what is causing the client side error you see ("The field Target Month must be a date").

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the 'TargetMonth' property on your view model to be a string, not a date.  Validate the string to match this regular expression:
'[0-1]?[1-9]/[1-2][0-9]{3}'

Then either add a get only property to your data model that parses the string and returns a DateTime instance, or do the conversion logic when you pass the value to its corresponding entity object for storage.