# Razor Page ignores DisplayFormat

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

I'm saving a date in a model like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Eintrittsdatum")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
[Required]
public DateOnly EntryDate { get; set; }
```

[But when I try to display it in my view it does this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdgOw.png) It doesn't matter if the DisplayFormat line is there or not, or what it says there, I can write just about anything, the program completely ignores that line.

After a bit of searching I found [this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697872/why-is-displayformat-dataformatstring-not-working)

Now my dates are correctly displayed but in [an editable text box,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiLu2.png) which isn't really what I want. Does anyone have a suggestion for a better solution or an explanation why my date looks like it does in the first picture?

Index.cshtml:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.Employee)
            {
            ...
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.EntryDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new {maxLength = 10})
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
            </td>
            ...
```

Index.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly PersonaleinstellungContext _context;

    public IndexModel(PersonaleinstellungContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public SelectList Departments { get; set; }
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string EmpDepartment { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        IQueryable<string> depQuery = from e in _context.Employee
                                      orderby e.Department
                                      select e.Department;

        var employees = from e in _context.Employee
                        select e;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            employees = employees.Where(s => s.LName.Contains(SearchString));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmpDepartment))
        {
            employees = employees.Where(x => x.Department == EmpDepartment);
        }
        Departments = new SelectList(await depQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());

        Employee = await employees.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format the display of a `DateTime`, you can simply provide a format string to the `ToString` method (as well as the salary):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Employee)
{
    <td>
        @item.EntryDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.Salary.ToString("c")
    </td>
    ...
```

Another thing - don't use Html helpers for rendering form fields in ASP.NET Core. Use tag helpers instead. Set the `DataType` to `Date`, the format string to an ISO 8601 string that the `input type="date"` understands, `ApplyFormatInEditMode` to `true` and let Razor Pages take care of the rest:

```
[Display(Name = "Eintrittsdatum")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DateType.Date)]
[Required]
public DateOnly EntryDate { get; set; }


<input asp-for="EntryDate" />
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/dates-and-times

Comment: Thank you for the response, that fixed it! I'm already using tag helpers for the inputs, only using Html helpers for the output but thanks for mentioning it anyways